# Local Persistent DNS Caching Server

Tags: kali-linux, dns

My goal is to set up a computer that can bypass DNS-based network filtering by relying on a semi-persistent cache in its own local DNS server.  I would like to configure it so that it relies on its own DNS cache, unless the requests can be fulfilled from a server at a specified IP address, but ignoring any replies given to it by local devices (for example, servers with traceroute of less than 3 hops).

Basically I want it to rely on either a global server or a persistent cache that can be updated by a global server, but to ignore any DNS redirects given by a local router or server by either checking the number of hops away the reply came from or if the reply points to a local address.  I also want the DNS cache to persist across server reloads/system restarts.

What would be the best way to set up something like this?  I'm running Kali Linux 2.0, a derivative of Debian Jessie.

Comment: The more I read your question, the more I see conceptual errors in your question.  Your DNS cache server needs to take its data from somewhere which will be filtered;  adding a traceroute to the DNS server's load will surely slow it down and is a most custom requirement;  "DNS redirects given by a local router" makes my brain stall...  router's don't do DNS redirects but if your router does redirect traffic to a different IP, you will not be able to know it; your computer can not hold all the DNS records you'll need; etc; etc

Comment: I would advise talking first with your local networking team, and then came back here with real Linux doubts, instead of your own made up theories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you'll find would be something like [Unbound](https://www.unbound.net) ("validating, recursive, and caching DNS resolver").

Unbound is available on Debian - and most likely on Kali.

```
# apt-get install unbound
# less /usr/share/doc/unbound/examples/unbound.conf
```

Enabling DNSSEC validation could help, although not everyone uses it.